# Can a Cleric with the Magic domain use Wands containing Wizard spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, cleric, domains

The Magic Domain's granted power says:

> Use scrolls, **wands**, and other devices with spell completition or spell trigger activation as a Wizard of one-half your Cleric level...

So can a Cleric without Use Magic Device, but with Magic domain use a Wand of Fireball?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The [Magic](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#magic) domain's granted power allows activating wands containing wizard spells without Use Magic Device skill checks

A creature that possesses the domain [Magic](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#magic) (*Player's Handbook* 188) can activate wands of wizard spells without resorting to the skill [Use Magic Device](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#use-magic-device). If the creature possesses that domain's granted power, such activation is automatic no matter the creature's level or Hit Dice and usually no matter the wizard spell the wand contains.

(The reason the granted power mentions using half the cleric's level for the cleric's effective wizard level is that [scroll activation](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsSSW.html#scroll-activation) is harder if the reader isn't high enough level.)